# Exercise: Using pointers cross-function in C Language returns error "invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)"

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new here so sorry if this post is not properly edited.

I'm currently trying to resolve some exercises using C, to put in practice some stuff I've been studying recently, but I keep getting several distinct errors when using pointers, which I'm not being able to figure out by myself.

In this case I have this challenge from Hackerrank, and I was supposed to return the sum of all the array's elements, but I keep getting this compilation error in line 12: `invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)`

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int simpleArraySum(int ar_size, int* ar) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ar_size; i++){
        sum += *ar[i];                     //line 12
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    int n; 
    scanf("%i", &n);
    int *ar = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for(int ar_i = 0; ar_i < n; ar_i++){
       scanf("%i",&ar[ar_i]);
    }
    int result = simpleArraySum(n, ar);
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

I know it involves the use of pointers, but I'm not sure how to handle it. I've tried using `int *sum = malloc(sizeof(int));` and `*sum += *ar[i];` but the same error persists.

Any advices?

Comment: the `[]` is already dereferencing your pointer. No need for the `*`

Comment: `sum = ar[i]` will work

Comment: It should be just `ar[i]`, not `*ar[i]`; the array-indexing operator implicitly dereferences the pointer.

Comment: try `sum += ar[i];`. The `[]` operator dereferences, so you don't need the `*`. Alternatively you could do `sum += *(ar + i);`, which is the same thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should not be `*ar[i]`, it should just be `ar[i]`.

```
int simpleArraySum(int ar_size, int* ar) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ar_size; i++) {
        sum += ar[i];              
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `*ar[i]` is invalid given the declaration `int *ar`.

Because the expression `ar[i]` is equivalent to `*(ar + i)`, the given expression is the same as `*(*(ar + i))`.

So you start with `ar` which is of type `int *`.  Then `*(ar + i)` is of type `int`.  So `*(*(ar + i))` is invalid because you're attempting to dereference a non-pointer type.

`ar[i]` by itself is enough to get the array element, so that's what you use in your expression.

```
sum += ar[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, when `ar` is an array of `int`s, you can access its elements as `ar[0]`, `ar[1]`, etc.

---

You got confused between `*ar` and `ar[...]`.

This is because the type `int*` can either mean:

- a pointer to an `int`, in which case you would usually write `*ar` ;
- an array of `int`s, in which case you would usually write `ar[0]`.

Side-note (might get confusing): `ar[0]` and `*ar` both do the same thing, they return the data at the address `ar`.

Comment: `*ar` is equal to `*(ar + 0)` is equal to `ar[0]`. All three notations are interchangeable, no matter if `ar` is defined to be an array or a pointer of/to any type.

Comment: `int *ar` *always and ever* defines a **pointer** to an `int` and *never* an array. Try to reword your answer, to be less ambiguous.

Comment: @alk regarding your 1st comment : that is why I wrote "usually" in both bullet points (one can use both notations, but they do not convey the same intent/meaning even though they do the same thing). Regarding your 2nd comment, `int *ar` defines a pointer yes but an array is roughly equivalent to a pointer (`sizeof` and nested arrays being corner cases). That's why I used the word "mean" and not something strict like equivalent. If you see a better way to express that without sidetracking the answer too much, I'm listening, otherwise I think the answer is good for a beginner.

Comment: The essential practical difference between defining a pointer to T and a variable of type T is that the latter allocates memory to hold T whereas the former doesn't. This might be obvious to you, but .... well .